# Display three column Bootstrap image grid using Advanced Custom Fields repeater field

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I'm wanting to display three images in one row using ACF repeater fields.

It looks right to me but it's not outputting the images. Any help would be appreciated!

```
      `<div class="container">
        <?php if (have_rows('image-grid')): ?>
          <div class="row">
          <?php while ( have_rows('image_grid') ) : the_row();
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" />
            </div>
          <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- end container -->`
```

Comment: Have you set the image field, to only return the url? or is it set to array?

Comment: It is set to array

Comment: You aren't accessing the array tho : read the documentation for sub fields here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/

Comment: basically, you should save the image array to a variable like this : `$image = get_sub_field('image'); ` and then use ´<img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" />´

Comment: I have updated it but am not having any luck. I've made the edit in my first post. Thanks @Stender

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($image)` ?

Comment: are you even hitting your `while` loop then? What html is being output?

Comment: The HTML it's producing is an empty container div @Stender

Comment: That means, that `(have_rows('image-grid'))` isn't being accessed - If you are outside the loop, you need the postid as a second parameter, another thing could be, that `image-grid` has a `-` and `have_rows('image_grid')` has an `_` basically... you might have a typo there

Comment: that might denifetly be it mate - image-grid should be image_grid

Comment: Thanks @Stender, that was a rookie mistake by me. I have fixed the typo but had a broken image display, i've since changed it to 
`<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" />` which displays one image but not three. Are you able to see what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Set the image field to only return the url?